# How to share data across multiple components with react-query useMutation

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm looking for a solution to share data across a React-Query mutation without having to create my own internal state or context.

I created a custom hook that takes care of the API call.

**myData.ts**

```
const useDataMutation = () => useMutation('MY_DATA_MUTATION', postData);
```

Then, I use my custom hook in different components.

Component1 is in charge of mutating. The response data will be available in `data` once the mutate is successful.

**Component1.tsx**

```
  const { mutate, data } = useDataMutation();
  
  useEffect(() => mutate('some_data'), []);
```

In another nested component, I want to access the data which came back from the response. But I don't want to pass down the data to 3-4 layers of components. And I wanted to avoid using a Context to access this data.

What I want is something like this:

**Component2.tsx**

```
  const { data } = useDataMutation();
  
  console.log({ data }); // log data once available.
```

But in this example, the data from Component2.ts is always undefined.

Is there a simple way to achieve something like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

at the moment, mutations don't share data across instances like queries do. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/2304) about it, and contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@apollo/client` then you can read the previously fetched data directly from the cache.

```
import Query from './query.ts'

const { todo } = client.readQuery({
  query: Query,
  variables: {}
})
```

That will not fetch the data from your server again and instead fetch it from the apollo cache.  So you can fetch it using the hook or in the parent component and then 5 levels down you can just pull it again from the cache using the same hook.

When you're using a mutation it will update data in the cache if the properties in the query is the same as before, so if you have a query for `getUser` and a mutation for `updateUser` I think the mutation should automatically update the getuser cache data if the data aligns with the mutation data.  I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `v5`, you can use `useMutationState` hook for this purpose, see [TanStack Query documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/reference/useMutationState).

In your case it will be something like

```
import { useMutationState } from '@tanstack/react-query'

const mutations = useMutationState({
    filters: { mutationKey: ['MY_DATA_MUTATION'] },
})
```

which gives you the array of all mutations for given mutation key. Then you can access the last item in the array to get the latest mutation and the data, e.g.:

```
const data = mutations.slice().pop().data;
```

Or, if you are interested only in data and not the whole state, you can use `select` option to get array of data from the hook:

```
const mutationState = useMutationState({
    filters: { mutationKey: ['MY_DATA_MUTATION'] },
    select: (mutation) => mutation.state.data,
})
```